# Why isn't the first executable in my $PATH being used?

Tags: path

I have a script called `jsl` in `/usr/local/bin`. Running `which jsl` finds it there.

I want to temporarily use a different version, and when I `echo $PATH` I see that `/usr/bin` is earlier in the path. So I added a script called `jsl` in that folder and I've verified that it is executable and runs correctly when called with the full path.

However, `which jsl` still finds the first version, and `jsl` still runs it.

Why isn't my new `jsl` being found by `which` or executed by name?

Comment: that is weird! I just tested with ls and put in my case in /usr/local/bin and after copying the file which reported the first instance in the $PATH. Using bash 4.2.45

Comment: Can you give the full results for `echo $PATH; which -a jsl`?

Comment: @CharlesStewart - `which -a jsl` outputs `usr/bin/jsl` followed by `/usr/local/bin/jsl`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The shell might be caching the command's location.  E.g. zsh does this, and has the `rehash` command to clear the cache.

Comment: in bash and other bourne shells, it's `hash -r` to clear the path cache.  bash's built-in help has more details - type `help hash`

Comment: `hash -r` also works in zsh BTW

Comment: That worked! Interestingly, `which -a jsl` showed both locations in the correct order, but immediately after, `which jsl` still showed the old one. After `hash -r`, `which jsl` showed the new one and `jsl` ran it.

Comment: `which -a js1` scans the path to find all executables called "js1".  This ignores the cache, because the cache is only used to find the one, first "js1", but a scan may include multiple hits.  In the case of `which js1` it is only looking for the first hit, so can make use of the cache (and therefore, when the cache is out of date, reports the wrong first hit).