# The command `which` does not show the path of command correctly

Tags: rhel, vim, path, which

My system is RHEL 7.5 and the output of `vim --version` as below:

```
me@localhost:~/tmp$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug  9 2019 03:17:15)
```

I want to use vim 8 so I downloaded the source code of vim 8, compiled it and installed it.

Now, when I type `which vim`, the output is `/usr/local/bin/vim`, which is exactly what I just intalled.

`/usr/local/bin/vim --version` showed me

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Apr 17 2020 12:27:50)
Included patches: 1-587
Compiled by me@localhost.localdomain
```

Everything looks fine.

However, if I execute `vim --version`, it's still vim 7, instead of vim 8.

Now I'm totally confused.

As my understanding, `which vim` tells me which command it will use, `which vim` shows me `/usr/local/bin/vim`, so why `vim --version` used another vim (`/usr/bin/vim`), instead of `/usr/local/bin/vim`?

Comment: The path may have been hashed by your shell - see for example [Why isn't the first executable in my $PATH being used?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91173/why-isnt-the-first-executable-in-my-path-being-used?)

Comment: @steeldriver   Ohh, thanks. `hash -r` helps.